# React ListView renderrow bind

Tags: react-native

When I run this code:

```
  render: function () {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
        renderrow = {this.renderBook.bind(this)}
        key={"list" + i}
        >
      </ListView>
    );
  }
});
```

I get this message:

> cannot read property `bind` of undefined,

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not bind(this) to functions in a render function. Do it in constructor or you can use ES2016 notation.

```
// constructor way
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.renderBook.bind(this)
}

// ES2016 way
renderBook = () => {}
```